# Invisible unicode characters in my post cause it not to format correctly?

Tags: support, markdown, code

UPDATE: It's formatted correctly after posting the question. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like when creating the question: http://cl.ly/3u072T2K0F2P2A2n0d3Q. I'm on Chrome v19.

Here's a d-paste of the code that I can't seem to format correctly on Stack Overflow: http://dpaste.com/765025/copy/.

Here's the code pasted as is, I've tried writing it manually as well... what could be the reason for this problem?

```
onTwitterInit : function () {
    if (window.twttr) {
        var that = this;
        window.twttr.anywhere(function (T) {          
            T.bind("tweet", $.proxy(that.onTweet, that));
            T.bind("follow", $.proxy(that.onFollow, that));
            T.bind("authComplete", $.proxy(that.onAuthComplete, that));
            T.bind("signOut", $.proxy(that.onSignOut, that));
            $.subscribe(EVENTS.LOGIN, function (e) {
                T.signIn();
            });
            $.subscribe(EVENTS.POST_STATUS, function (e, data) {
                if (T.isConnected()) {
                    T.Status.update(data.text); 
                } else {
                    that.customTweet(e, data);
                }
            });
            $.subscribe(EVENTS.GET_STATUS, function (e) {
                if (T.isConnected()) {
                    that.onAuthComplete(null, T.currentUser)
                } else {
                    that.onSignOut();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain what the problem is? Looks formatted alright.

Comment: Browser? O/S? Screen shot demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Chrome 19 - uh and yes it is now aligned correctly - it was not aligned correctly in the preview mode

Comment: Screenshot: http://cl.ly/3u072T2K0F2P2A2n0d3Q

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I reproduced that

```
onTwitterInit : function () {
    if (window.twttr) {
        var that = this;
        window.twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
```

doesn't get rendered properly in the preview:

> [image: screenshot]

The culprit is a Unicode character (code `8232`) following the `{` on the last line. If you remove it, the rendering problems disappears.

`U+2028` is the Unicode character 'LINE SEPARATOR', and the preview engine doesn't seems to handle it properly. I checked on Chrome, Firefox and IE. All have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! Was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are seeing?

### IE9 Compatibility Mode

[image]

If so, then turn off Compatibility Mode

### IE8 Mode

[image]

### IE9 Mode

[image]

Comment: I'm in chrome - thanks for the fast response - it's only unformatted when previewing the question - on a side note, I did not know you could include screenshots, so thanks +1